# wave bot and xmpp bot?

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, google-wave

1. Wave protocol bot is just like any typical xmpp agent bot / component bot right?
2. Can wave bots used on other places or use bosh and create webclient to consume the bot?
3. Is wave protocol bot library created using ignite whack library? if yes, can we just use directly whack library to create component bot for wave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, wave bots operate over HTTP. Currently, they have to be written on App Engine.
2. No, but you could potentially create a container that does HTTP requests to the wave bot using the same protocol as Wave itself.
3. No, for the reasons outlined above.